# Enable MVVM object only if three other MVVM objects are already enable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I know that this question might be a dummy for an expert in C#, but for me, it's quite confusing to solve.

So, what I have are 4 buttons. All the buttons are 4 different MVVM objects. And what I want is to enable button A only if buttons B,C,D, are enabled.

**XAML file**

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestEnvironment.MainWindow"
        x:Name="MainWindowScreen"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestEnvironment"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        Title="My dummy tool"
        Height="720"
        Width="1145"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5"
        WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid x:Name="GridMain"
              Width="1145"
              Background="White"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              ShowGridLines="False" 
              Grid.Row="1">
            <!--Grid Columns-->
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="195"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="295"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="650"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--Grid Rows-->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="52"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="400"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button 
            x:Name="Button_A"
            Click="Button_A_Click"
            Content="Run"
            IsEnabled="{Binding EnableButtonA}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Width="80"
            Height="25"
            Margin="135,0,0,0"
            FontSize="10"
            FontWeight="Light"
            Background="{StaticResource CalculationsButtonColor}"
            BorderBrush="{StaticResource CalculationsButtonColor}"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.Row="4"
            Cursor="Hand"/>
        <Button
            x:Name="Button_B"
            Command="{Binding Path=ViewTableCommand}"
            Background="{StaticResource PreviewButtonColor}"
            BorderBrush="{StaticResource PreviewButtonColor}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EnableButtonB}"
            Content="View"
            Width="80"
            Height="25"
            Margin="545,0,0,0"
            FontSize="10"
            FontWeight="Light"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Cursor="Hand">
        </Button>
        <Button 
            x:Name="Button_C"
            Command="{Binding Path=ViewTableCommand}"
            Background="{StaticResource PreviewButtonColor}"
            BorderBrush="{StaticResource PreviewButtonColor}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EnableLButtonC}"
            Content="View"
            Width="80"
            Height="25"
            Margin="545,0,0,0"
            FontSize="10"
            FontWeight="Light"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Cursor="Hand">
        </Button>
        <Button 
            x:Name="Button_D"
            Command="{Binding Path=ViewTableCommand}"
            Background="{StaticResource PreviewButtonColor}"
            BorderBrush="{StaticResource PreviewButtonColor}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EnableButtonD}"
            Content="View"
            Width="80"
            Height="25"
            Margin="545,0,0,0"
            FontSize="10"
            FontWeight="Light"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Cursor="Hand">
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**.CS file - MVVM model**

```c
namespace TestEnvironment
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //Button B
        private bool _enableButtonB;
        public bool EnableButtonB
        {
            get
            {
                return _enableButtonB;
            }
            set
            {
                _enableButtonB = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EnableButtonB");
            }
        }

        //Button C
        private bool _enableButtonC;
        public bool EnableButtonC
        {
            get
            {
                return _enableButtonC;
            }
            set
            {
                _enableButtonC = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EnableButtonC");
            }
        }

        //Button D
        private bool _enableButtonD;
        public bool EnableButtonD
        {
            get
            {
                return _enableButtonD;
            }
            set
            {
                _enableButtonD = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EnableButtonD");
            }
        }

        //Button A - What I tried so far
        private bool _enableButtonA;
        public bool EnableButtonA
        {
            get
            {
                return _enableButtonA;
            }
            set
            {
                if (EnableButtonB == value && EnableButtonC == value && EnableButtonD == value)

                    _enableButtonA = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EnableButtonA");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above I presented both the XAML file (with some custom buttons) and the cs file with the MVVM model developed. As mentioned earlier I want to Enable `Button A` only when the rest of the three buttons are enabled. Otherwise, if at least only 1 is disabled then the `Button A` should also be disabled.

During my search to solve this, I came across DataTriggers in XAML but I am not confident to judge if DataTriggers is a more efficient approach than MVVM binding. Thus, I stuck around MVVM model. Thanks in advance for your insights and answers.

Comment: Why not use ICommand for button A as well and apply the conditional logic there

Comment: @Nkosi yeah, I will use ICommand for Button A but I have not implemented it that yet. Although it's on my schedule. What you propose it's ofc an option However, is there any alternative way to achieve this without first making an ICommand for Button A? Because I want button A to be disabled whether or not it's clicked.

Comment: When you bind a button to ICommand it will be enabled based on the CanExecute member, which can be dependent on the status of the other buttons' commands

Comment: @Nkosi ok show I create my ICommand and I add ```CanExecute()``` method that will check for the other three buttons (not status of ICommands but status of property ```IsEnabled```)

Comment: Update the post with the properties showing the other commends and also how they were initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use this:

```
 //Button B
        private bool _enableButtonB;
        public bool EnableButtonB
        {
            get
            {
                return _enableButtonB;
            }
            set
            {
                _enableButtonB = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EnableButtonB");
              EnableButtonA=value;
            }
        }
private bool _enableButtonC;
        public bool EnableButtonC
        {
            get
            {
                return _enableButtonC;
            }
            set
            {
                _enableButtonC = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EnableButtonC");
               EnableButtonA=value;
            }
        }

        //Button D
        private bool _enableButtonD;
        public bool EnableButtonD
        {
            get
            {
                return _enableButtonD;
            }
            set
            {
                _enableButtonD = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EnableButtonD");
                 EnableButtonA=value;
            }
        }

        //Button A - What I tried so far
        private bool _enableButtonA;
        public bool EnableButtonA
        {
            get
            {
                var enable=EnableButtonB & EnableButtonC & EnableButtonD;
                if(enable!=_enableButtonA) _enableButtonA=enable;
                return _enableButtonA;
            }
            set
            {
                if(!value) _enableButtonA=value;

                else
                    _enableButtonA = EnableButtonB & EnableButtonC & EnableButtonD ;
               
                OnPropertyChanged("EnableButtonA");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make EnabledA property read-only (since it's calculable) and change its getter like this:

```cs
    public bool EnabledA {
        get { return EnabledB && EnabledC && EnabledD; }
    }
```

And also view should be notified that EnabledA changes, so you need to add:

```cs
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EnabledA));
```

to all Enabled_X setters.

BTW, use nameof(fieldName) construction instead of "fieldName" - that will give ability later automatically rename field

Comment: Quercus also your approach seems to work. Thanks a lot for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in XAML using a [`MultiBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.multibinding?view=net-5.0) and a [converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter?view=net-5.0). A multi binding allows you to bind multiple values and convert it to a single value for the target property. In your case, you would bind the three enabled state properties and and do a boolean AND as conversion.

The following multi-value converter returns `true`, if all passed values are `true`, otherwise `false`.

```
public class BooleanAndConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return values.Cast<bool>().All(value => value);
   }

   public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}
```

In your XAML, you would bind the `IsEnabled` property for button A like this:

```
<Button 
   x:Name="Button_A"
   Click="Button_A_Click"
   Content="Run"
   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
   VerticalAlignment="Center"
   Width="80"
   Height="25"
   Margin="135,0,0,0"
   FontSize="10"
   FontWeight="Light"
   Background="{StaticResource CalculationsButtonColor}"
   BorderBrush="{StaticResource CalculationsButtonColor}"
   Grid.Column="3"
   Grid.Row="4"
   Cursor="Hand">
   <Button.IsEnabled>
      <MultiBinding>
         <MultiBinding.Converter>
            <local:BooleanAndConverter/>
         </MultiBinding.Converter>
         <Binding Path="EnableButtonB"/>
         <Binding Path="EnableButtonC"/>
         <Binding Path="EnableButtonD"/>
      </MultiBinding>
   </Button.IsEnabled>
</Button>
```

You could also bind the the `IsEnabled` properties of the other buttons directly, e.g:

```
<Binding Path="IsEnabled" ElementName="Button_B"/>
```

By the way, you could do the same using a `MultiDataTrigger`, but that would require creating a separate button style, which is more verbose and unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and the answer. Indeed searching about my question online many used multi-binding and converter. Unfortunately, my inexperience with C# coding prohibited me from creating such a solution. So many thanks for providing an alternative solution. It always helps others to be able to choose among different solutions. Kudos :)

Comment: I would like to ask you a question about your answer. *Please advise me if I should post a new question or not.* If one of the three *enable booleans* was an ```Image```. So for example I want to enable ```Button A``` if ```Button B``` & ```Button C``` are enabled and also ```Button D``` instead of a Button now is an ```Image``` that should have this icon ```BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/checkmark.png", UriKind.Relative))```. Can you explain to me what should I change in your answer? Thanks a lot

Comment: @DelusionX I think that you should ask a separate question for that. You would not compare the `BitmapImage`, but the `Uri` instead, but it depends on your code.

Comment: I have posted a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65091754/enable-button-when-certain-conditions-apply