# Enable button when certain conditions apply

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Enable button_A when button_B is enabled and image source has a specific .png icon

I have two `Buttons` and an `Image` object in a WPF application built with .NET Core and C#. What I want on the bottom line is to enable `Button_A` only when the `Button_B` is enabled and the `Image` has a specific .png icon of a checkmark. For those three objects an MVVM model exists. More details in the code below,

**XAML file**

```xml
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="1080"
        Width="1920"
        ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid x:Name="MyGrid"
              Background="White"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              ShowGridLines="False">
            <!--Grid Columns-->
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--Grid Rows-->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button 
            x:Name="Button_A"
            Click="Button_A_Click"
            Content="Execute"
            IsEnabled="{Binding EnableButtonA}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Width="80"
            Height="25"
            Margin="135,0,0,0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button
            x:Name="Button_B"
            Click="Button_B_Click"
            Content="Execute"
            IsEnabled="{Binding EnableButtonB}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Width="80"
            Height="25"
            Margin="135,0,0,0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="1">
        </Button>
        <Image
               x:Name="IconSymbol"
               Source="{Binding Path=ImageChangeSource,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Width="{Binding Path=CalculationsImageWidth}"
               Height="Auto"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="190,0,0,0"
               Visibility="Visible"
               IsEnabled="True"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**.CS file - MVVM model**

```cs
namespace MyApp
{
    public class CustomViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //Button B
        private bool _enableButtonB;
        public bool EnableButtonB
        {
            get
            {
                return _enableButtonB;
            }
            set
            {
                _enableButtonB = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EnableButtonB");
            }
        }
        
        //Image
        private ImageSource _imageChangeSource;
        public ImageSource ImageChangeSource
        {
            get
            {
                return _imageChangeSource;
            }
            set
            {
                _imageChangeSource = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ImageChangeSource");
            }
        }

        //Image width
        private int _changeImageWidth;
        public int ImageWidth
        {
            get
            {
                return _changeImageWidth;
            }
            set
            {
                _changeImageWidth= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ImageWidth");
            }
        }
        
        //Button A
        private bool _enableButtonA;
        public bool EnableButtonA
        {
            get
            {
                return _enableButtonA;
            }
            set
            {
                //What to write here?
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

What I tried so far is based on this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64845361/enable-mvvm-object-only-if-three-other-mvvm-objects-are-already-enable/64855679?noredirect=1#comment115074452_64855679) I asked in the past. A [relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64855679/14456332) posted in the attached question is the use of `IMultiValueConverter`. However, I am not confident to figure out how to properly use the Converter for my task.

(The code below won't work)

```cs
public class EnableReportConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((bool)values[0]=true, (ImageSource)values[1]=new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/checkmark.png", UriKind.Relative)));
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

```xml
<Button 
    x:Name="Button_A"
    Click="Button_A_Click"
    Content="Execute"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Width="80"
    Height="25"
    Margin="135,0,0,0"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.Row="0">
    <Button.IsEnabled>
      <MultiBinding>
         <MultiBinding.Converter>
            <local:EnableReportConverter/>
         </MultiBinding.Converter>
         <Binding Path="EnableButtonB"/>
         <Binding Path="ImageChangeSource"/>
      </MultiBinding>
   </Button.IsEnabled>
</Button>
```

[EDIT]--example of an `ICommand`

```cs
public ICommand ButtonACommand
{
    get { return new DelegateCommand<object>(FuncBrowseFileCommand); }
}
public void FuncBrowseFileCommand(object parameters)
{
    var final_result = BrowseFile(FilesFilePath);
    Nullable<bool> browse_result = final_result.browse_result;
    FilesFilePath = final_result.filename;
    
    //below are some MVVM object-- dont pay them attention
    if (browse_result == true)
    {
        EnableFilesLoadButton = true;
        EnableFilesBrowseButton = true;
        EnableFilesViewButton = false;
        FilesPanelVisibility = false;
    }
    else
    {
        FilesImageVisibility = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Better approach**:
I understand "WHAT" you need but , I am not sure "WHY" you need this. There are better ways to enable a button. I also notice that you are using button click which is obviously code behind. When you have MVVM model, try to use ICommand and attach to the "command" property of the button. If you do that , then you can easily assign a delegate to  "CanExecute" to make the enabling of the button.

**Solution to current problem**: Regardless of the above suggestion, solution to your current problem is as below.

The below line in your converter is wrong. This returns object[] again. Basically, you receive an array from the XAML and return the same again. You need to receive the array, process it and return a result (which is "bool" in your case : to enable a button).

```
return ((bool)values[0]=true, (ImageSource)values[1]=new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/checkmark.png", UriKind.Relative)));
```

So, do the validation like below..

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
//INCOMING DATA
    bool is_buttonB_enabled = (bool)values[0]; //This is the first value in the object array.

    ImageSource _image = (ImageSource) values[1]; //This is the second value in the object array.

//YOUR EXPECTED IMAGE.
    ImageSource _expected_image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/checkmark.png", UriKind.Relative));

//VALIDATE
    return (is_buttonB_enabled == true && _image == _expected_image );
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
In case, you use an ICommand (and return a delegatecommand), then you can follow below approach.

```
    public ICommand ButtonACommand
{
    get { return new DelegateCommand<object>(FuncBrowseFileCommand,_canEnableButton); }
}

    private bool _canEnableButton(object obj)
{

//YOUR EXPECTED IMAGE.
    ImageSource _expected_image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/checkmark.png", UriKind.Relative));


return (EnableButtonB == true && ImageChangeSource == _expected_image );

}
```

then, you don't need converter..

Comment: Lingam thanks a lot for your answer. It is vey well explained. Appreciate the effort you made to add comments on your script. I indeed use an ICommand for every different Button I use to replace the ```Click``` property. Since I have also received a similar suggestion about ```CanExecute``` can you post also the code only for the ```CanExecute``` method? I use ICommands but without ```CanExecute()``` property most of the times. In any case I will accpet and upvote your answer.

Comment: Please share some code showing how you use the Icommand. Do you use any Delegate command? If so i can show example of how to use it in your case.

Comment: Yeah ofc let me provide an example in my question text above. Check my edit

Comment: When you use, DelegateCommand<Object> I assume it is taken from Prism or any other external library.. So, I will update the answer based on that.

Comment: Exactly! Prism it is :)

Comment: I am directly typing the code part in the answer. So, excuse any minor typos. I wrote the _canEnable method as void. It is actually a function to return bool. So, please find the updated answer.

Comment: So basically ```_canEnableButton``` is the ```canExecute``` method right? I may also use this approach whenever I can. Thanks again for the effort Lingam.

Comment: Lingam can I want to ask you something about the ```_canEnableButton()```. How do I know that it's connected to the ```ICommand```? When the command is executed that it indeed returns ```true``` or ```false```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225376/discussion-between-lingam-and-delusionx).